# Count content views show in number with icon

Tags: nodes

I have enabled Count content views in Statistics.
[image]

The bottom of article show "3 reads".

I checked the code, the code is `<span>3 reads</span>`

Because the number and word is together, I can't change word "reads" to an "eye" icon.

How do I show the number with icon.

[image]

Below is the effect I want

[image]

Comment: Please provide the Drupal version?

Comment: Drupal 7 @Yogesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using D7, you can implement [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/hook_node_view) in your custom module and override statistics count text as per your requirement. Check example below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function [YOUR_MODULE_NAME]_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if ($view_mode != 'rss') {
    if (user_access('view post access counter')) {
      $statistics = statistics_get($node->nid);
      if ($statistics) {
        // Alter text as per your requirement below.
        $links['statistics_counter']['title'] = format_plural($statistics['totalcount'], '<i class="icon"></i>1 read', '<i class="icon"></i>@count reads');
        $node->content['links']['statistics'] = array(
          '#theme' => 'links__node__statistics',
          '#links' => $links,
          '#attributes' => array('class' => array('links', 'inline')),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just looked into the statistic folder and remove the word "read‘ and "reads" in 2 files which are statistics.test and statistics.module. Now it is okay.

Comment: Do not modify Core statistics module file, this is bad practice and if you update Drupal Core, this will break again. Instead you can implement `hook_node_view()` in your custom module and override text as per example given above.

Comment: Which file should I edit?

Comment: You've to create your own [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules), and inside your module's `.module` file, you need to implement [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/hook_node_view) hook. So suppose if you've created a module named `custom_module` then you'll implement `custom_module_node_view()` function in your `custom_module.module` file. Check [how implement hook](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-comments-and-implementing-your-first-hook) guide for more details.